# MVC sign in to IdentityServer4 without redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jwt, identityserver4, dotnet-httpclient, httpcontext

So I'm trying to sign in users from my ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC app without redirecting them to IdentityServer4. So far I'm able to use IS4's `ResourceOwnerPassword` flow to get a token and get a token with `RequestPasswordTokenAsync`, but even after I set my client with the access token it's not authenticating my app.

**Controller:**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
        {
            Address = "http://localhost:5000/connect/token",
            ClientId = "mvc3",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            UserName = "LegitUsername",
            Password = "VeryLegitamitePassword",
            Scope = "api1"
        });

        client.SetBearerToken(response.AccessToken);

        return Redirect("/");
}
```

**Current behavior:** Token is granted, but my header still has the "Login" button

**Expected behavior:** Token is granted, "Logout" button is displayed

The current behavior suggests that I haven't been authenticated even though I'm holding the token. I know I'm missing something to pass the token to the `HttpContext` to authenticate my app, but can't figure out what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should not be using ResourceOwnerPassword

Comment: @DaImTo Okay. Got any an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do not log in the user. You request an access token from id4. Normally you request an access token to add it to a request (as you did) to access a resource.

Please refer to the examples: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/Clients/src

There are several examples implementations for mvc.

Comment: Checked out **all** of the samples and only projects that reference `RequestPasswordTokenAsync` are console projects that so the same as my original posted code.

Comment: Well, you are doing the wrong thing. I guess you copied it from somewhere. You see in the field "scope" in your code where to use it. Please read the following to understand the different token types. What you are looking for is the id token. the id token is the result of authentitcation and this needs to be handled. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/terminology.html additionally it is important to thing in user, clients, identityserver and resources.   it seems you try to implement the client. to make the client working you need to handle the id token.

Comment: maybe you do not what to user identityserver but just identity. this is something you should think about, you need to do much more.